# Removing unused resources

Tags: android, android-resources

I have successfully made an app. Currently it is showing 1.6 MB download size after using pro guard. However, after analyzing signed APK, it seems that there are many unused .png resources.

After fiddling through explorer, I could not seem to find any file named "drawable-xxhdpi-v4". The file according to APK analyzer contains generic Android icons. hdpi-v4, xxxhdpi-v4 and xddpi-v4 all contain generic icons.

I am using sweet dialog box as the only 3rd party library. How do I delete it? Is it safe to delete?

Secondly, what other procedures are there to reduce APK beside proguard? [image: Demo]

[image]

Comment: Those folders contain drawable images/icons for various screen sizes, densities, etc: Those images, icons will be used whne the system detect the screen size corresponding

Comment: But since I am not using any generic icons/images, I am sure they would be of no use since my app does not seems to use them in any way?

Comment: Your app does surely have a launcher icon, doesn't it? And your app will be installed in various devices which have various screen sizes and densities

Comment: Please check updated post above. I am not sure if you understood what I was saying. What I was saying is that the folder contains such generic icons. I dont understand how these will be put to use on different screen sizes even when my app is not using any of them in UI.

Answer (score 2):

Not Necessary should see only resource whice used in layout, There some things come automality with project libraries and you can't remove it because In fact they really used
in you application

But you can remove main unused resource using:

MenuBar -> Analyze -> Run inspection by Name -> Unused resource